# How to package a electron application which is being uses by puppeteer?

Tags: launching

I want to package my electron app which is using puppeteer and distribute it to windows and mac users. After reading the docs of puppeteer I configured the installation of chromium inside my local project repo and I could see the chromium file.

While launching the puppeteer, I gave the path of the chromium and it is working fine, but when I package my app, it says that it could't detect the chromium.